# SQL group by on query and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I have a few tables grouped together:
Divisions > Sessions > Registrations > Registration Week Days

Each Division has several sessions, each session has several registrations, and each registration has weekday options (either M-F, MWF, T/Th).

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT d.Name, r.Weekdays, COUNT(r.weekdays) from divisions d
left join sessions s on s.DivisionID = d.ID
left join registrations r on r.SessionID = s.ID
order by r.Weekdays
```

This query contains all the info I need but I'm trying to group by in such a way to get weekday option count for each division, kind of like this:

```
Div | Weekday Option| Count
Div1| M-F           | 4
Div1| MWF           | 5
Div1| T/Th          | 3
Div2| M-F           | 7
```

This shouldn't be too tough for SQL adepts, but my group by statements keep leaving out information I need and I'm not quite sure how to get the format above.  Any suggestions would be great and I'm sure there are several right answers!

Comment: Missing `group by` clause? `group by d.Name, r.Weekdays` ? Without sample data it's hard to know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try in to group "d.Name, r.Weekdays" columns?
Code is here:

```
SELECT d.Name, r.Weekdays, COUNT(r.weekdays) 
FROM divisions d
    left join sessions s on s.DivisionID = d.ID
    left join registrations r on r.SessionID = s.ID
group by d.Name, r.Weekdays
order by r.Weekdays
```

Comment: Ah I just noticed I was only seeing half of the table returned and it looks confusing to order by weekdays instead of divisions in this case... You're right!  This is what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked.